# discord.js bot joining vc and playing audio

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to detect when a specific user joins a voice channel so that the bot joins that same voice channel and starts playing audio.

My code doesn't work: the bot doesn't join the channel. How can I fix this?

```js
const bot = new Discord.Client();
bot.login('BOT TOKEN');

bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
  let newUserChannel = newMember.voiceChannel
  let oldUserChannel = oldMember.voiceChannel
  let textChannel = oldMember.guild.channels.get('TEXTCHANNEL ID')

  if(oldUserChannel === undefined && newUserChannel !== undefined) {

    if (newMember.id === 'MEMEBER ID')         //Member 1
    {   
       newUserChannel.join()
       .then(connection => {
          console.log("Joined voice channel!");
          const dispatcher = connection.playFile("C:\Users\NAME\Documents\Welcome_Bot\music\bossman.mp3");

          dispatcher.on("end", end => {newUserChannel.leave()});
       })
        .catch(console.error);
      }
      else if (newMember.id === 'MEMEBER ID')      //Member 2
      {
       textChannel.send('Hello Member 2')
      }
      else if (newMember.id === 'MEMEBER ID')      //Member 3
      {
        textChannel.send('Hello Member 3')
      }
      else                                         //Random
      {
        textChannel.send("Hello") 
      } 
   } 
});
```

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?